# How to add noise to image?

Tags: python, image

I've attempted through the code below, to add Gaussian noise to an RGB or a GRAYSCALE image, but until now I have the same problem, the result is always as follows:

[image: current results]

So is there a problem with the code I've written?

```
def gauss(mean,sigma):
     from random import uniform
     from math import sqrt,log,pi,cos
     a=uniform(0,1)
     b=uniform(0,1)
     x=sqrt(-2*log(a))*cos(2*pi*b)
     return(x)

def bruiter(image):
     from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
     if len(image.shape)==3 :
       a,b,c=image.shape
          for i in range(a):
             for j in range(b):
                 image[i][j] += [gauss(0.5,0.01),gauss(0.5,0.01),gauss(0.5,0.01)]

     elif len(image.shape)==2 :
       a,b= image.shape
          for i in range(a):
             for j in range(b):
                 image[i][j] +=  gauss(0.01)*(1/255)

return(image)
```

Comment: what is the expected result? this would also be far more concise with numpy vector adds

Comment: Your code doesn't _add_ noise to the image, it effectively _replaces_ it with noise. You need to make the result for each `image[i][j]` be a function of the value which is already at the location and `gauss()`, rather than being completely independent of it as shown. I also suspect that the `elif len(image.shape)==2:` should be `elif len(image.shape)==1:` for grayscale images.

Comment: P.S. Python includes [`random.gauss()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.gauss) Gaussian distribution random number function.

Comment: I hope I've given you a more suitable answer now.

Comment: Possible dup of [**_How to add and remove noise from an image_**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701604/how-to-add-and-remove-noise-from-an-image).

Answer (score 2):

My thanks are due to Mr Martineau for pointing out that I should be answering about noise and not blur. I will answer in terms of Pillow again because I think it makes like simpler.

I open a picture of a muskrat's paw and display the image size and the value of the pixel at position (50,50). This is a RGB image and we can be fairly sure that each colour can range from 0 to 255.

I think you want *additive* Gaussian noise. To save myself the bother of writing and debugging a generator I'm using one that's readily available, `normalvariate`. You will want to vary the level and spread of the noise; I've therefore made the mean and scale parameters. Since there are limits on the ranges of the colour values I use `max` and `min`. As a convenience I package three calls to `add_noise` in `add_noise_one_pixel` so that this latter routine can be called once for each pixel in the image.

You will already have noticed that all pixels in the image can be addressed in a using knowledge of the size of the image and the `getpixel` method.

I have NOT checked this code. It's meant more as an illustration of principle.

```
>>> from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
>>> im = Image.open('muskrat.png')
>>> im.size
(100, 117)
>>> im.getpixel((50,50))
(121, 130, 116)
>>> import random
>>> def add_noise(x, mean, stddev):
...     return min(max(0, x+random.normalvariate(mean,stddev)), 255)
... 
>>> def add_noise_one_pixel(im, x, y, mean=10, stddev=5):
...     x, y, z = im.getpixel((x,y))
...     im.putpixel((x,y), add_noise(x, mean, stddev), add_noise(y, mean, stddev), add_noise(z, mean, stddev))
...
```

Old answer:

If you just want to **do it** rather than concern yourself about the details about doing it then have a look at Pillow. It's this easy.

```
>>> from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
>>> im = Image.open('GENES.png')
>>> im2 = im.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(5))
>>> im2.show()
```

Comment: [Gaussian blurring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) is **not** the same thing as adding [Gaussian noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_noise) to an image.

Comment: Good to know (assuming I remember).

Comment: In fact, the blurring has the opposite effect and it's often used to _remove_ (or a least somewhat hide the) noise already in an image.

Comment: Oddly enough, I've used it for that but not in code, only in picture editors, and the name didn't mean anything to me in this context.